# Service that checks if token hasnt expired

Tags: spring, spring-security

so I have a authentication bean which provides access tokens from client credentials.

```
public class AuthServiceBean {
    @Value("${some.url}")
    private String someUrl;
    @Value("${some.clientId}")
    private String someClientId;
    @Value("${some.secret}")
    private String someSecret;
    @Value("${some.username}")
    private String someUsername;
    @Value("${some.password}")
    private String somePassword;
    public AuthInfo getPrevAuth() {
        return prevAuth;
    }
    public void setPrevAuth(AuthInfo prevAuth) {
        this.prevAuth = prevAuth;
    }
    private AuthInfo prevAuth;
    public AuthInfo getAuthInfo() throws IOException {
        if (this.prevAuth != null && this.prevAuth.isNotExpired()) {
            return this.prevAuth;
        }
        return this.Authenticate();
    }
    private AuthInfo Authenticate() throws IOException {
        final String url = this.someUrl + "/api/oauth/v1/token";
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
        String clientIdSecret = this.someClientId +":"+ this.someSecret;
        String authString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(clientIdSecret.getBytes());
        headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + authString);
        MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
        map.add("username", this.someUsername);
        map.add("password", this.somePassword);
        map.add("grant_type", "password");
        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> request = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>(map, headers);
        ResponseEntity<?> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, request, String.class);
        String bodyString = response.getBody().toString();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            AuthInfo authInfo = mapper.readValue(bodyString, AuthInfo.class);
            this.prevAuth = authInfo;
            return this.prevAuth;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And now how do I need to create service which checks if that access token valid if it hasn't expired and how to use refresh token. When access token expires I could ask new token with refresh token? Would be good to get any examples.

Comment: Have you  Googled for an example of spring application with token based authentication ?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, As I see in your code, you are using password grant type, not client credentials, and because of this, you pass also user credentials (username and password) in addition to the client credentials, client id and client secret.

Anyway, the reason because all the examples you found to check expiration are using jwt tokens is because these tokens have this information coded in the token itself, so you can parse it using some kind of library like Nimbus Jose and get the "exp" claim and check directly if that date is before or after the actual date.
If the token is an opaque one (not jwt). You don't have any way to check the expiration without call the server who issued that token. Normally the server (an oauth2 server) provides and endpoint called introspect in which you pass a token and it responds indicating if this token is valid or is not, because it has expired or it is revoked etc..